# Expectation of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

If $X$ has the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, how do you show for $k=0,1,2,...$ that

$\mathbb{E}(X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-k))=\lambda^{k+1}$?

Can you show this using induction, and if so how? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Won't the expectation be negative for some values of $k$?

Comment: No, because $\lambda$ isn't negative

Comment: But won't some of your $X-k$ factors will cause the expectations on the left hand side to be negative?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: I think you're right! Careless of me. Do you specifically want an induction argument, or is some other argument ok?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to prove this is by using the probability-generating function for a Poisoon random variable $X$
$$
\mathbb E[t^X]=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} t^x \mathbb{P}(X=x)=e^{\lambda(t-1)}
$$
Then taking the derivative $k+1$ times,
$$
\mathbb E[X(X-1)(X-2)\ldots(X-k)t^X]=\lambda^{k+1}e^{\lambda(t-1)}
$$
and setting $t=1$,
$$
\mathbb E[X(X-1)(X-2)\ldots(X-k)]=\lambda^{k+1}
$$